# A question on Lebesgue measure: Inequalities

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, measure-theory, self-learning, lebesgue-measure

Let $A_n$ be a decreasing sequence of Borel sets with finite but with measure $\geq \epsilon > 0$ for all $n$. Then there exists a compact set $B_n \subset A_n$ for all $n$ such that $\mu(A_n \setminus B_n) < \frac{\epsilon}{2^{n+1}}$ for some $\epsilon >0$. Then define $C_n := \cap_{k=1}^n B_k$. It is clear that $C_n \subset B_n \subset A_n$. ***Then how come we have $\mu(A_n \setminus C_n) < \frac{\epsilon}{2}$ and $\mu(C_n) > \frac{\epsilon}{2}$, please?*** I tried the following argument.

$$
\mu(A_n \setminus C_n) = \mu\left( A \setminus \cap_{k=1}^n B_k \right) = \mu \left( A_n \cap \left( \cap_{k=1}^n B_k \right)^C \right) = \mu \left( A_n \cap \left( \cup_{k=1}^n B_k^C \right) \right) = \mu \left( \cup_{k=1}^n \left( A_n \cap   B_k^C \right) \right) = \mu \left( \cup_{k=1}^n \left( A_n \setminus B_k \right) \right) \leq \sum_{k=1}^n \mu(A_n \setminus B_k)
$$

I cannot see how to proceed from the above to show the two results.

Comment: This is false unless you assume $\mu(A_n)<\infty$, there is no such compact set for, say $A_n=B(0,n)^c$.

Comment: @AdamHughes Thank you for pointing that out. I forgot to mention it. How to show the results after I assume what you said?

Comment: Also, the condition $\mu(C_n)>{\epsilon\over 2}$ is false. If all the $A_n$ have measure $0$, for example, then sub-additivity says all the $C_n$ have measure $0$.

Comment: @AdamHughes I guess I should add $A_n$ has non-zero measure. And the whole point is to show that $C_n$ is not empty.

Comment: @AdamHughes Thanks. What about the second result? BTW, it is allowed to comment on your answer.

Comment: The second result cannot be true for any $A_n$ satisfying your conditions:  even with $\mu(A_n)>0$ for every $n$, as soon as you fix $\epsilon$ you're in trouble because $C_n\subseteq A_n$ and we could have $\mu(A_n)\to 0$ as $n\to\infty$, so that we cannot force $\mu(C_n)$ to be uniformly bounded away from $0$.

Comment: With these new hypotheses, the rest is easy. See my edited answer.

Comment: @AdamHughes Thank you! Yes, I figured that much. That is why I deleted the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We use that

$$A_n\setminus C_n=A_n\cap\left(\bigcup_{k=1}^n B_k^c\right)$$
$$=\bigcup_{k=1}^n (A_n\cap B_k^c)\;\subseteq \;\bigcup_{k=1}^n (A_k\cap B_k^c)$$
$$=\bigcup_{k=1}^n (A_k\setminus B_k)$$

then

$$\mu(A_n\setminus C_n)\le\sum_{k=1}^n\mu(A_k\setminus B_k)=\sum_{k=1}^n {\epsilon\over 2^{n+1}}<{\epsilon\over 2}.$$

---

**Edit to reflect edited question**

Now note that

$$\mu(B_1\cup (A_1\setminus B_1))=\epsilon\le \mu(A_1)= \mu(B_1)+\mu(A_1\setminus B_1)\le\mu(B_1)+{\epsilon\over 4}$$

so that

$${3\epsilon\over 4}\le\mu(B_1)$$

Now continuing on like this, we see that

$$\epsilon\le \mu(A_n)=\mu(C_n)+\mu(A_n\setminus C_n)< \mu(C_n)+{\epsilon\over 2}$$

i.e.

$${\epsilon\over 2}<\mu(C_n).$$